# Metadata de un archivo pdf

Tags: linux, pdf, línea-de-comandos

Estoy trabajando en linux.

Como se podría saber si un archivo pdf tiene incrustado algún vídeo ?, por linea de comando.

Answer (score 0):

```
pdfdetach -list archivo.pdf
```

`pdfdetach` es parte de [poppler](https://poppler.freedesktop.org/).

Es muy probable que `poppler` esté en los repositorios de tu distribución.

Answer (score 0):

Podemos usar [qpdf](https://qpdf.readthedocs.io/en/stable/cli.html#pdf-inspection)

```bash
qpdf --list-attachments in.pdf
```